# Accessing object parameters declared in different buttons

Tags: java, fxml

```
  Player p1 = null;
@FXML
private void enterName  (ActionEvent event){
String playerName = nameField.getText();    
p1 = new Player(playerName);
System.out.println(p1.name);
}

 @FXML
public void pickAndesite (MouseEvent event){

  System.out.println(p1.name);

}
```

Whenever I click the pickAndesite button, an exception appears.
My player class looks like this

```
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;   
}
```

Why does it throw an Exception? I already put parameters in p1.name

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: I don’t get any clue from your exception but looking at your code for the second time. You have two variables with same name which is p1 and you are trying to acess p1 in the second method here in this case it would be null. So don’t create a new object just assign it to the existing p1 object. Let’s see if this works for you.

Comment: another exception is  Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException showing if i remove the  Player p1 = new Player(playerName);

Comment: It happens when i use the first button

Comment: Don’t remove that line instead have it like this, p1= new Player(playerName); In this case you are not assigning to the local variable

Comment: it works again for the first, but does has another exception for the 2nd button,

Comment: Which IDE you are using try having the debug point and debug on the line you are getting exception look at the exception stack trace in which you can get the line number

Comment: There is a null pointer exception at System.out.println(p1.name); of the pickAndesite button

Comment: Please repaste your modified code.

Comment: I repasted it already

Comment: Ok got your problem as you are listening for the MouseEvent it gets called even before the first method so do a null check in your second method. if (p1 != null) {s.o.p(p1.getName());

Comment: Im sorry, but what is a null check

Comment: is the code correct? it says s is not a package

Comment: Sorry s.o.p is a shortcut for System.out.pritntln